# Graylog TLS client authentication Unknown beats protocol version

Tags: docker, graylog

I want to make beat input work with TLS client authentication without it works
So I made custom graylog image with selfsigned certificates

```
FROM graylog/graylog:4.3
USER root
ADD beat.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/beat.crt
RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/beat.crt && update-ca-certificate
```

Next I made beat input with tls auth requared

```
bind_address: 0.0.0.0
no_beats_prefix: true
number_worker_threads: 80
override_source: <empty>
port: 5044
recv_buffer_size: 1048576
tcp_keepalive: false
tls_cert_file: <empty>
tls_client_auth: required
tls_client_auth_cert_file: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/beat.crt
tls_enable: false
tls_key_file: <empty>
tls_key_password:********
```

And set filebeat on another machine
folder "tls" added as volume when running filebeat in docker --volume="/home/filebeat/:/tls"

```
output.logstash:
hosts: ["graylog_ip_here:5044"]
ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/tls/beat.pem"]
ssl.certificate: "/tls/beat.crt"
ssl.key: "/tls/beat.key"
```

beat crt look inside like so pem is the same file

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFVzCCAz+gAwIBAgIJALJI6zP
```

After all this had been set I'm getting error on graylog server

***ERROR: org.graylog2.plugin.inputs.transports.AbstractTcpTransport - Error in Input cause io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown beats protocol version: 3)***

Comment: So probably I missunderstood things and I need set tls_cert_file too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in documentation [here](https://go2docs.graylog.org/5-0/setting_up_graylog/secured_graylog_and_beats_input.html) you should apply both steps to make it work. The first step is to set up a TLS exchange. The second is for authenticating specific users.

**TLS Beats Input**

```
To enable TLS on the input, a certificate (and private key file) is needed. It can be the same or 
a different certificate as the one of your REST/web interface, as long as it matches all hostnames 
of your input. Just reference the files TLS cert file and TLS private key file in the Beats Input 
configuration and restart the input.

The ingesting client will verify the presented certificate against his know CA certificates, 
if that is successful communication will be established using TLS.
```

**Add client authentication to Beats input**

```
Create one directory (/etc/graylog/server/trusted_clients ) that will hold all client certificates 
you allow to connect to the beats input. This directory must be available on all Graylog server 
that have the input enabled. Write that path in the beats input configuration 
TLS Client Auth Trusted Certs and select required for the option TLS client authentication.

After this setting is saved only clients that provide a certificate that is trusted by the CA 
and is placed inside the configured directory (/etc/graylog/server/trusted_clients) 
can deliver messages to Graylog.
```